# Word Search comes back correct but with a extra line '(None)'

Tags: python

Basically I am trying to made a simple tool to search for words within text a user provides. I get the correct response saying its found if that is true yet I have a line beneath saying None. I am not sure when I am going wrong, any help would be great cheers!

```
    def search(text, word):
    if word in text.split():
        print('Word found')
    else:
        print('Word not found')

text = input()
word = input()

print(search(text, word))
```

Comment: `search` doesn't return anything don't print it, just call it: `search(text, word)`

Comment: That worked, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search` does not return anything, which means, in Python, that it implicitely returns `None`. This means that when you `print(search(text, word))`, you actually print `None`.

The fix is easy: turn `print(search(text, word))` into `search(text, word)`.

Answer (score 0):

`search` method didn't return anything. So, when you call it `None` will be printed.
If you want `search` return the answer and then you print it change your code to below:

```
def search(text, word):
    if word in text.split(): 
        return 'Word found'
    else: 
        return 'Word not found'

text = input() 
word = input() 
print(search(text, word))
```

Or you can just call `search` out of print in your code

```
search(text, word)
```